# Extracting data from Marketing Cloud via SOAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap

I'm getting a 403 - Forbidden response when I try to submit my ExtractRequest via the SOAP API using a temporary access token obtained from the REST API using the xxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/Token endpoint.

Note that I was at least getting an "OK" when I did this using a UserNameToken for authentication but that was having other issues, and I'd prefer to use an access token anyways.

Also note that I'm using a GET instead of a POST, as when I used POST it was throwing a "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed."

My raw code:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com
content-type: text/xml
SOAPAction: "Extract"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
     <fueloauth>[token provided by REST token Endpoint]<fueloauth>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <ExtractRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Requests>
          <ID>c7219016-a7f0-4c72-8657-1ec12c28a0db</ID>
            <Parameters>
              <Parameter>
                  <Name>StartDate</Name>
                  <Value>09/01/2019 12:00:00 AM</Value>
              </Parameter>
              <Parameter>
                  <Name>EndDate</Name>
                  <Value>01/01/2020 12:00:00 AM</Value>
              </Parameter>

              [...etc...]

            </Parameters>
        </Requests>
      </ExtractRequestMsg>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Relevant portion of response:

```
<h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
<h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
```

EDIT: I've checked the Installed Package used for generating the token, and I can't imagine what access level could be missing. I've got Read/Write on everything that seems meaningful.

EDIT: Scope of Installed Package I most recently tried:

```
Access: Offline Access
Email: Read
Web: Read
Documents and Images: Read, Write
Saved Content: Read, Write
Automations: Read, Write, Execute
Audiences: Read, Write
List and Subscribers: Read, Write
Marketing Cloud Connect: Read
Data Extensions: Read, Write
File Locations: Read, Write
Tracking Events: Read, Write
Callbacks: Read
Subscriptions: Read
```

EDIT: Issue was compounded by the FuelAuth closing tag being screwed up. Fixed. Used xxxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx endpoint and POST verb. I'm hesitant to say the other question linked to answered my question as technically the endpoint in their solution (webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx) did not work for me.

Comment: What scope does your token have

Comment: Scope of the one I'm currently using...Access:Offline Access...Email:Read ...Web:Read...Documents and Images:Read, Write...Saved Content:Read, Write...Automations:Read, Write, Execute ...Audiences:Read, Write ...List and Subscribers:Read, Write ...Marketing Cloud Connect:Read ...Data Extensions:Read, Write ...File Locations:Read, Write ...Tracking Events:Read, Write ...Callbacks:Read ...Subscriptions:Read

Comment: It needs to be a POST with the right endpoint. This is a dupe of another answer.

Comment: identigral, not so much. That person is using the older UsernameToken authentication. Installed Packages offer a different SOAP API endpoint for their use. For what it's worth when I use the other endpoint (xxxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx) with this method of authentication, it just throws a generic "an error has occurred" response. Also, using POST just throws a "bad request" with the legacy endpoint and a "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed." with the one I'm currently using.

Comment: Check that. Found the issue. Turns out the above solution does work, but was being hindered by my closing fuelauth tag...well, not being closed. I'm still confused as I've seen other solutions that implied that the correct endpoint is the one the package actually provides, but hey, I got a response.

Comment: Final Comment: the above got me on the right track but please note that the endpoint they used, "webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx", didn't work for me. I basically just added "/Service.asmx" to what I already had. See above.

Comment: Every correct endpoint for soap ends with /Service.asmx regardless if its TSE or stack endpoint